# how to Secure javascript calls WebAPI from a mvc app

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I've designed a mvc view in my MVC4 website which allows members to update their user details. This works ok using MVC but if i create a partial view which allows users to update their address for example using AJAX. How can i apply  a level of security to determine that user x can only update userx's account. And not allow a user to login as user x and then spoof a  post and update user y's account?

Comment: Are you using any authentication currently? Forms, Windows, etc. ? You could use the built in Authentication Model to check who the user is.

Comment: I don't see the webapi part here. Are you trying to hit a webapi controller from that view? It seems that you have it working fine on mvc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regardless if your controller is an MVC controller or a WebApi controller, after the user authenticates and the Principal is set in the current thread, all you have to do is check that  the user in the current context:

```
HttpContext.User
```

Is the one the data being edited belongs to.
Usually the username is populated on

```
HttpContext.User.Identity.Name
```

If the username of the user being edited is different than the authenticated user, just throw and InvalidOperationException.